# JQuery Autocomplete - multiple data post not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

```
        $("#textjawatan" + noid).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "pendaftar_table.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term : "pe" } ,
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                    });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                    $("input#jawatan" + noid).val(ui.item.no);
            }
        });
```

when i use

> data: { term : "pe" }

its work, but when i use

> data: { term : "pe", id : "jawatan" }

its doesnt work, what is the problem ?

Comment: what is the error? server side not receiving?

Comment: the error is autocomple not work, it didnt show request data

Comment: server side working, i didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem not too long ago. Let me explain in quick words.

As jQuery Autocomplete explain in their site http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ jQuery Autocomplete **only accepts TERM as output for server**. Let me quote the page

> **Function:** The third variation, a callback, provides the most
>   flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to
>   Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments: A request object, with
>   a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the
>   text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field,
>   the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo". A response callback, which
>   expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data
>   should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of
>   the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when
>   providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the
>   request. You must always call the response callback even if you
>   encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the
>   correct state.

In other words, if you even add 250 extra hashes to the json dict, it will only work TERM to server side.

**How did I fix this?**

What I did was this. Based on jQuery docs, the source can also be an ARRAY, so i did an ajax call to my server BEFORE setting the jQuery autocomplete and then feed the autocomplete plugin.

**Note:** This is not a very good fix, and I'm aware of it. But I had to do it due to my work's details and is just an option.

Comment: thanks for that, it works now, i make in array  before send it